# Run a script until a different output is generated

Tags: bash

I'm writing a C++ program to find the minimum number in a text file in parallel, but I've intentionally introduced a race condition.

I now want to run this program until I can show that there was a different output. Obviously for such a trivial problem, the output will **generally** be correct, but I want to stop running the program once there's evidence of a race condition.

The command I will be running continuously is `./openMP < numbers.txt`

The pseudocode for what I want to do in a bash script would be something like this:

```
$MIN=output_from_program_on_first_run
$TEMP=output_from_program_after_first_run
while [ "$MIN" -eq "$TEMP" ]
do
  $TEMP=output_from_program_after_first_run
done
echo $TEMP
```

My question is how can I store the output from `./openMP < numbers.txt` into $MIN and $TEMP?

Thanks,
erip

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, variable assignments in `bash` do *not* use the dollar sign (`$`) along with the name. For example you should write

```
HAS_FOO="true"
```

rather than:

```
$HAS_FOO="true"
```

As for storing the standard output of a program in a shell variable, `bash` offers [two different ways](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html#Command-Substitution):

```
TEMP=`./openMP < numbers.txt`
```

and

```
TEMP=$(./openMP < numbers.txt)
```

However, for a slightly safer journey:

```
TEMP="$(./openMP < numbers.txt)"
```

The double quotes will prevent the shell from trying to expand the output of your program, which can be a bit of a problem if it contains characters that are special to the shell.

Comment: Shows how little I know about bash scripting. It is running now without error!